# Links extending to other side of screen

Tags: html, css

For some reason the links are extending from the divs to the other side of the screen. I've tried putting a class in the links to limit its size but that obviously didnt work. I also tried limiting the wrapper size. That also didnt work. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.image {
height: 40px;
width: 50px;
}
.b {
background-color: #E5DF00;
width: 60px;
padding: 15px 15px 12px 20px;
font-size: 50px;
color: white;
}
.fb {
background-color:  #2B65B2;
}
.fb:hover{
background-color:  #2C5489 !important;
}
.b:hover {
    background-color: #DAD400;
}
.code {
    width: 50em;
    background-color: #ECECEC;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0;
    height: 315px;
}
html, body {
margin: 0px;
}
.tw {
background-color: #4B98FF;
}
.tw:hover {
background-color: #398EFF;
}
sWrapper {
width: 60px;
position: relative;
}
#open { display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br />
<div class="sWrapper" id="buttons">
<font style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;"> See us on </font>
<a href="https://www.minds.com/*">
<div class="b">
<img src="https://s11.postimg.org/ek580pzqr/test.png" class="image">
</div>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/*">
<div class="b fb" >
<center>
<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</center>
</div>
</a>
<a href="https://www.twitter.com/*">
<div class="b tw">
<center>
<i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</center>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT: I do not want them inline. If i click the white space to the right of them the link still works.**

Answer (score 3):

Because you put DIVs into them. DIVs are block elements and by default have `width` 100%, thereby spanning the whole width of the parent element.

Comment: How can i avoid this?

Comment: You can use `span` tags instead of those DIVs - spans are inline by default.

Comment: Or you define smaller width values for those divs - I have no idea which result you expect...

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want ?

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 105px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Long text</a>
```

Comment: Example of the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzmacKNa7tvrdGdscmRHc0gwX2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Use `.b{ display:inline-block }` for the width to work. Same applies to any element. It should be a `inline-block`.